# ArgoCD: How to deploy and target specific cluster in ArgoCD?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm, cicd, argocd, argoproj

In ArgoCD how to target a deployment into a specific cluster or a group of clusters in a multi-cluster environment ?

Comment: Are you looking for the `destination` key in an `Application`? https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#applications

Comment: I was trying to find a way to run deployments to multiple openshift/kubernetes clusters,  I found how to do it by adding generators with clusters selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the right way to deploy to multiple clusters is by using generators, clusters with selectors like below:

```
generators:
  - clusters:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          staging: true
```

Full Example:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: bgd
  namespace: openshift-gitops
spec:
  generators:
  - clusters:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          bgd: dev
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{name}}-bgd'
    spec:
      project: default
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/christianh814/gitops-examples
        targetRevision: master
        path: applicationsets/cluster-generator/overlays/dev/
      destination:
        server: '{{server}}'
        namespace: bgd
```

More details can be found here: https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/getting-started-with-applicationsets